# ack does not work when run from "grep-find" in Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, emacs, ack

I'm trying to use [ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) as a replacement for grep + find in Emacs on Windows, but ack-grep exits immediately (successfully) without printing any matches. I've tried just about every conceivable combination of command-line parameters to ack-grep, but nothing seems to work.

```
M-x grep-find
```

Enter "ack html" to search for files containing "html". Ack exits immediately, printing nothing:

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "c:/" -*-
Grep started at Tue Feb 23 23:50:52

ack html

Grep finished (matches found) at Tue Feb 23 23:50:52
```

Executing the same command "ack html" in `cmd.exe` works fine (showing lots of various files containing the string "html".

Any ideas?

Comment: "Executing the same command "ack grep" in cmd.exe" - do you mean "ack html" ? Do you not have to provide it any file names to search? (I am not quite sure how these things work on Windows, where you don't have proper pipes). On linux grep-find gives you a default command running find, and you customize that, including providing the string to search and optionally changing the find invocation as well

Comment: Silly question, but is ack in the PATH? Could be emacs can't find ack to run it

Comment: What version of ack and what version of Emacs?

Comment: And it's called "ack".  Debian just calls it "ack-grep" because they already had a different program called "ack".

Comment: "ack html" means "search for files under cwd containing the string 'html'". Edited post to clarify.

Comment: "ack" is in the path; I tried putting a printout "I'm here!" in it, which is displayed fine, so "ack" is actually invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running ack under Emacs in Windows, I found it sometimes got confused about whether it was supposed to search files or read from STDIN.  Here's the function I use to call ack (use `M-x ack`).  You can put this in `.emacs`.

```
(defvar ack-command "ack --nogroup --nocolor ")
(defvar ack-history nil)
(defvar ack-host-defaults-alist nil)
(defun ack ()
  "Like grep, but using ack-command as the default"
  (interactive)
  ; Make sure grep has been initialized
  (if (>= emacs-major-version 22)
      (require 'grep)
    (require 'compile))
  ; Close STDIN to keep ack from going into filter mode
  (let ((null-device (format "< %s" null-device))
        (grep-command ack-command)
        (grep-history ack-history)
        (grep-host-defaults-alist ack-host-defaults-alist))
    (call-interactively 'grep)
    (setq ack-history             grep-history
          ack-host-defaults-alist grep-host-defaults-alist)))
```

Comment: Yay! Thanks, that was it. I actually tried passing "-f" to ack to see which files it tried to parse, but then it complained about "cannot use -f in filter mode". That should've been a hint, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`(setq grep-find-command "ack <nul -i ")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the `ack-and-a-half` module, closing STDIN did the trick there too. There's an issue on github: https://github.com/jhelwig/ack-and-a-half/issues/23