# How to use ack with M-x find-grep?

Tags: emacs, find, grep, ack, find-grep

Leaving question here for reference. The Lord alone knows why, but whereas once upon a time this didn't work for me, prompting me to ask this question, today it does. Typical bloody emacs. Also typically, it is an utter joy once you've wrestled with it a bit. YMMV.

These two commands:

```
find ~/myco -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep -nH -e "setjmp"
```

and

```
ack --no-heading --no-color "setjmp" ~/myco
```

Seem to me to produce very similar results at the terminal.

And yet when I try to use the second as the command with `M-x find-grep` in emacs, it just prints the results, rather than hyperlinking and highlighting them as it would with the first.

Anyone know what is happening? Initial experiments with ack at the command line indicate that it blows find and grep out of the water, so it would be nice to be able to use it from emacs too.

Comment: You might have use of "--group", it must be placed before "--no-heading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows I call ack from find-grep e.g. like this:

```
c:/xampp/perl/bin/perl.exe c:/bin/ack-standalone.txt --type-set java=.java --type=java -i information
```

and it's working perfectly. The results are linked and colored in the grep buffer. I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but I can say it does work here.

emacs version: GNU Emacs 23.2.1

ack version: 1.94

Comment: I've accepted this answer because today, it is working for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs tries to show the output of `find-grep` in a buffer in `grep-mode`. Apparently `grep-mode` (surprise, surprise) doesn't understand the output format of `ack`. Use a dedicated [ack-mode](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/full-ack/).

Comment: Well, I haven't downvoted you, but the two commands seem to produce identical results at the console, so the question is *why* doesn't grep-mode understand. Thanks for the link to ack-mode though, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden I just found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322389/ack-does-not-work-when-run-from-grep-find-in-emacs-on-windows Others suggest that `grep-mode` should work with ack. I'd rather be on the safe side and go for the easy solution. :)

Comment: This answer isn't useful. It works perfectly for me too, so much that I'm now switching from "ack-mode" to "find-grep"! Must me some problem with the specific ack and emacs versions.

Comment: Ooops It is not quite so.... sorry for the downvote (can't take it back). On Windows it works almost perfectly, since the match itself isn't highlighted. In Linux it only seems to work if you open the ack output in a buffer and apply grep-mode to it explicitly.

Comment: @JoaoTavora You can take back downvotes. Just click on the downvote button again. Anyway, I tried to point out in the comment that this might be a windows problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this ack-mode to work better, and out of the box. Some more coloring would have been nice, but at least it's readable:

https://github.com/sudish/ack-mode.el